# The primary key in the database is 32 bytes whitespace when I use Ruby to add a record

Tags: mysql, ruby

This is the code I use to add a record to database:

```
 def vis_attribute(email){
   :v_uid => 'default_visitor',
   :v_name => 'default_visitor',
   :password_expiration=>(Time.now + 60 * 60 * 24),
   :last_used_timestamp=>(Time.now - 60 * 60 * 24),
   :v_login_id => email,
   :v_password => 'MMM',
 }

 class vis < ActiveRecord::Base
  def add
    @vis = create vis_attribute('AAABBB@MAI.COM')
  end
 end
```

`v_uid` is the primary key.

The field `@vis.v_id` is `0` after I run that.

I'm running MySQL version 5.6.22-enterprise-commercial-advanced MySQL Enterprise.

My Gemfile is:

```
gem 'activerecord', '~> 3.0'
gem 'mysql', '2.9.1'
```

the v_id definition in database `v_uid | varchar(32) | NO | PRI | NULL | |`
Does anyone know the reason for this?

Comment: And in the database, the v_uid field is 32 bytes whitespace

Comment: There is not enough information to replicate the problem. How is v_id defined? What column type is it? Are you within a AR model?

Comment: Also that method definition is wrong. It should have the outer curly brackets and should terminate with an end.

Comment: Where are you defining the primary key? Can you provide the code you used to create the table - either SQL or ActiveRecord migration

Comment: the v_id definition in database `v_uid           | varchar(32)  | NO   | PRI | NULL                |       |`

Comment: And my ruby version is 2.2.1. It works well in ruby 1.8.

Comment: @ReggieB, Please do not modify code samples in questions or answers. It's considered a bad-edit. Instead, explain to the OP what is wrong and they can change it. Fixing grammar and spelling and indentation is considered OK and is expected, but the code itself is sacrosanct. Even small corrections such as adding a missing `end` can cause confusion, especially if that was the source of the problem that triggered the question.

Comment: @the-tin-man fair enough. I've reversed my edit.

Comment: @AngleTom, when asked for more information, please edit your question and add the information into the text of the question, not as comments. Add the information into the normal flow of the question; You don't need to mark it as "Edit:" or call it out. If we need to see where it changed we can look at the edit history. Adding data/info as comments means we have to read every comment and try to piece together their timeline to figure out what we need to do, which only slows our answers.

Comment: @ReggieB, thank you. AngleTom, note that your code is not syntactically correct. That is the first thing to fix. Also, you haven't given us enough information. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I think the ActiveRecord 3 do some magic.

I solve the problem as follows.

```
def add
    @vis = new vis_attribute('AAABBB@MAI.COM')
    @vis.v_uid="default_visitor"
    @vis.save!
  end
```

no matter you set `self.primary_key = :visitor_uid` or not, the `new` method will ignore the primary key.

Anyone knows why the method `new` in ActiveRecord do like this.